# Problems in simulating using Cmdenv

Tags: omnet++

I have been learning about OMNET++ with simu5G for the past few months and i encountered a problem when trying to simulate the network using command line (Cmdenv). The setup works fine with Qtenv, however, when i try to change the user interface to Cmdenv, i got error such as below:

> Simulation batch Finished with Error <!> Error: Network '' or
> 'simu5g.simulations.demo.' not found, check .ini and .ned files

I have tried to change my working directory to a higher level, but it would results in error to parsing the xml file.

Looks forward for your kind help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the simulation in cmd mode using gui window,

you can edit the run configurations (next option below "run as").

1. Select a value for configuration field. Not selecting a value here is raising the error you reported.
2. Change the option for user interface field from "Qtenv" to "Cmdenv"